# Proof regarding angle between velocity vectors

Tags: velocity, vectors

Consider a casual trajectory of a point and the velocity vector at two istants $v_1$ and  $v_2$. In picture (1) I considered the osculating circle with center $O$ and radius $R$. In the picture (2)  I considered the same trajectory and velocity vectors, an origin $O'$ and the two position vectors $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Below I considered the two velocity vectors: there is an angle $\theta$ between them.

[image]

In case (1) I can say that $\alpha=\theta$, right? But in case (2)? Can I say that $\beta=\theta$?

Comment: The question is: as you change the origin, does the angle between the position vectors always match the angle between the velocity vectors.  1) Does the angle between velocity vectors ($\theta$) change when you change the origin?  2) Does the angle between the position vectors ($\beta$) change when you change the origin (consider extreme examples)?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Trivial counterexample would be if the origin, o, is just below the tangent point for v1, directly below it.  In that case, beta clearly can be 90 degrees or more, even if v1 and v2 are actually in the same direction!

Answer (score 1):

To add to Dilithium Matrix's answer, to simplify, you can look at $v_1$ and $v_2$ as any vectors, not necessarily velocity vectors.  We know that if $a = b$ and $b = c$, then $a = c$.  Hence, to say that $\theta = \beta$ is to say that $\alpha = \beta$.  You can then use geometry to show that there is only one other case where, for $O' \neq O$, $\alpha$ will be equal to $\beta$.  For all other points, they will not be equal.